# Adding binaries to the 'bin' catalog

Tags: linux, macos, phantomjs

When I'm trying to add 'phantomjs' binary to the 'bin' folder (/usr/bin) on Mac OSX, the following error occurs:

```
Oskars-MacBook-Pro:bin oskarszura$ mv phantomjs ../../../../usr/local/bin/
mv: rename phantomjs to ../../../../usr/local/bin/phantomjs: Permission denied
```

i assume that I shouldn't change this catalog's permissions. How should I add binaries on Mac OSX ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need administrator (also called root) rights to fiddle with the system folders.

See the [`sudo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) command how gain those privileges for a single command.

---

Also, instead of using that relative path to `/usr/local/bin`, why not simple use the full path of just `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: I guess it's a better way to describe paths - I'm very starting with OSX (a Windows user) so have no experience in it. Thank You for advice.